# What to be Tested in Layered Dependency Injection

Tags: unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection, automated-tests

The relative question maybe like this [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316848/unit-testing-what-not-to-test).

I used a dependency injection as architecture of my application. Then I have created unit testing for it.

The injection architecture may be like this:

```
IClassA(IClassB)
IClassB(IClassC1, IClassC2)
//more of it
```

Please take a note that this architecture only involve service objects, not repositories. Now I am wondering, what class to be tested.

- If I test class C1 and C2 (the smallest class), class B and A is not tested.
- If I only test class A (the integrated class), then there are too many scenario to be covered, instead of many small modules.
- If I test class A for it's module, and also test class C1 and C2, I think it seems redundant. If I want to refactor a logic (during development), I need to manage many test units.
- If I test class A with mock class B, it will create almost 1:1 for each class and mock class. Won't it create too much mocking?

Any suggestion or thoughts will be appreciated.

EDIT:

A working scenario is for when I want to give a file info (for csv or xml based), then convert to an entity. The process will be:

- ClassA read the data, passed it to ClassB as a big table format (maybe in DataTable)
- ClassB do the validation using ClassC1
- ClassB do more validation using ClassC2, then returning the header-detail mapped entity.

An example code for Classes will be like this (I skip the constructor injection part):

```
public class ClassA: IClassA{
  public IEnumerable<Request> GetRequestFromFile(FileInfo info
    , ref ValidationResult validationResult){
    //read the file and get DataTable
    iClassB.ConvertToRequest(dataTableResult, ref validationResult);
  }
}

public class ClassB : IClassB{
  public IEnumerable<Request> ConvertToRequest(DataTable dt
    , ref ValidationResult validationResult){
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows){
      // convert to flat request first, to avoid reading DataTable too much
      iClassC1.Validate(rawRequest, ref validationResult);
      iClassC2.Validate(rawRequest, ref validationResult);
    }
    if(validationResult.IsSuccess){
      // convert and return the header-detail entity object
    }
  }
}
```

N.B: Please ignore the logic architecture (ex: about not throwing exception during validation, etc)

Comment: please provide some sample code. If you test ClassA i assume it would make sense to mock ClassB so you do not depend on the outside world which is quite what we want in unit testing. When all your unit tests finally pass you ould think about integration tests.

Comment: @MarcoForberg I have updated a real case implementation for this. Maybe it can help to understand the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always mock all outside influences, so you test the functionality of one thing and one thing only. It may require a lot of mocking, but that is not really an issue with all the available mocking frameworks out there (such as Rhinomocks, Moq and many others).

Following that rule, you should always:

- Mock `IClassB` when testing `ClassA`
- Mock `IClass1` and `IClass2` when testing `ClassB`

If you do not mock injected objects, you will get confusing test failures, during refactorings. Further, your tests will be integration tests and not unit tests, as they depend on the implemetation of outside classes.

**Example:** You are testing `ClassA` in the `ClassATesFixture`. Instead of a Mock of `IClassB` you decide to use the production code `ClassB` as input. The test is OK. Now, you refactor `ClassB`, and introduce an error. This will result in a testfailure in `ClassATesFixture`, although nothing in ClassA has changed.

So, if you use real objects as intput in your tests, you are actually testing much more than just the object you set out to test. On top of that, you will also get confusing testfailures.

Ideally, no test should go from green to red, unless something in the tested class has changed. Mocking is the way to achieve this goal.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Really appreciate it, I think I know what I must doing. I have provided an example for this real-case scenario, maybe it can strengthen your points.

Comment: In my experience, when you "require a lot of mocking", there is something wrong with the design of your application. The applications I build are designed around just a few carefully chosen generic abstractions which cover about 70% to 95% of the services in the system. This allows me to write just a few generic mock objects (one for each generic abstraction), which has made the use of mocking frameworks redundant in most cases.

Comment: @Steven: Yes, if your classes need a lot of input different input, and thus need a lot of mocking, there is probably a design flaw, but that is not a flaw introduced by the mocks. I am just saying that in my unit tests, quite a big chunk of the code is about setting up mocks.

Comment: @Steven Currently I don't use mocking framework, and by several reasons currently I can't. However thanks for your advise, I will try to learn those mocking framework for further use.

Comment: Both answers are emphasizing for mocking injected dependencies. I choose this answer as it has examples and mentioned some auto-mocking frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstand the term "unit testing". Unit testing means testing classes in isolation. In your case you should do that by passing fake dependencies into the class to test. If you don't use fake dependencies in the classes you test, you are not testing those classes in isolation and you are therefore not doing unit testing. What you're doing in that case is integration testing.

So what you should do is unit test ALL classes and since you're practicing dependency injection, it should be very easy to fake out a classes dependencies under test.

Comment: Yes, looks like I misunderstood unit testing and integration testing. Thanks for pointing that out, now I understand what I must and must not do.