# What do unit tests not test?

Tags: java, c++, unit-testing

I was asked this in an interview, I have always read about what unit tests do, but what do they not do?

[Is Unit Testing worth the effort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299/is-unit-testing-worth-the-effort)

Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: I guess the answer is "They don't test what you don't tell them to test"

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084336/what-should-not-be-unit-tested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316848/unit-testing-what-not-to-test

Comment: @BackSlash Thats what I said, but they expected something else!

Comment: and thats a dupe but not on SO https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147055/when-is-unit-testing-inappropriate-or-unnecessary

Comment: @tobi303 its not a dupe, my questions asks what can unit test no do, not when they are not needed!

Comment: yep also realized it after writing the comment...

Comment: They don't test what's not in the scope of a "unit", e.g. interactions with other classes/systems.

Comment: And before anybody asks: no - LoveMeow isnt a sock puppet of GhostCat ;-) ... but I have to admit: I like that nickname.

Comment: The answer is: *They don't test for (find) **bugs***, Unittests verify *desired behavior*.

Answer (score 3):

"Good" unit tests are meant to test **units** in **isolation**. Period.

Thus a "real" unit test will **not** exercise those dependencies of your class under test - that **you** decided to "cut out" (using mocking/stubbing).

Of course that means that you do not test assumptions how that 3rd party API will react to your calls for example. Because you mock out that 3rd party API.