# Moq setup methods

Tags: c#, moq

I need to test many similar methods

```
public interface ITest
{
    void Method1(bool readMode, List<int> list);
    void Method2(bool readMode, List<int> list);
    void Method3(bool readMode, List<string> list);
...
}
```

Testing all methods is very similar:

```
public void Method1Test()
{
    Mock<ITest> test = new Mock<Itest>();
    test.Setup(x=>x.Method1(It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<List<int>>()).Verifable();
    // do stuff
    test.Verify(x=>x.Method1(true, It.IsAny<List<int>>()), Times.AtLeastOnce());
    test.Verify(x=>x.Method1(false, It.IsAny<List<int>>()), Times.Never());
    test.Verify(x=>x.Method1(It.IsAny<bool>(), It.Is<List<int>>(y=>y.Count == 0)), Times.Never());
    test.Verify(x=>x.Method1(It.IsAny<bool>(), It.Is<List<int>>(y=>y.Count == 2)), Times.Once());
}
```

For Method2 testing will be the same except method name. For Method3 besides method name, parameter type is changed. Is there any way to extract all this to helper generic function and pass parameter type and method to test?

I would like to write something like this:

```
public void Method1Test()
{
    TestAnyMethod<int>(x=>x.Method1);
}
public void Method2Test()
{
    TestAnyMethod<int>(x=>x.Method2);
}
public void Method3Test()
{
    TestAnyMethod<string>(x=>x.Method3);
}
```

Comment: In nunit there is an attribute called [testcase] you need to look up something like that and for same function look for [SetUp] attribute

Comment: I think this could be done with passing in an appropriate delegate/action. I will have a play and see if I can come up with a suitable answer

Comment: Are you actually testing all these methods, or mocking the methods to test the behavior of other methods? Either way, something here smells to me. You may be able to find a better way of modeling your class than having multiple almost-identical methods that you have to invoke or test in almost exactly the same way. Chances are you can refactor out the repetitive bits.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, that was my first thought reading the question, but I think the `// do stuff` is the 'act' of the test, and that is most likely consuming this interface as a service, so I think the question is valid. Definitely, you could have a class that has 3 similar signatures with 3 entirely different behaviours. It does smell a bit, but a smell isn't always bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by creating Expressions for verification base on passed Method

```
// Helper function to get It.IsAny<T>() Expression
public static System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression IsAny<T>()
{
    return System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(typeof(It).GetMethod("IsAny").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)));
}

// Helper function to check conditions for list.Count
public static bool CheckProperties(System.Collections.IList list, int expected)
{
    return list.Count == expected;
}

public void TestMethod1()
{
    var test = Mock.Of<ITest>();
    Mock.Get(test).Setup(x => x.Method1(It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<List<int>>())).Verifiable();
    //do stuff
    // Method1 passed as parameter
    TestAnyMethod<int>(test, x => x.Method1);
}

public void TestAnyMethod<T>(ITest test, Func<ITest, Action<bool, List<T>>> methodToTest)
{
    var type = typeof(ITest);
    var param = Expression.Parameter(type);
    var method = type.GetMethod(methodToTest(Mock.Of<ITest>()).Method.Name); // Method that will be tested

    //test.Verify(x => x.METHOD(true, It.IsAny<List<T>>()), Times.AtLeastOnce());
    var call = Expression.Call(param, method, Expression.Constant(true), IsAny<List<T>>());
    Mock.Get(test).Verify(Expression.Lambda<Action<ITest>>(call, param),Times.AtLeastOnce());

    //test.Verify(x => x.METHOD(true, It.IsAny<List<T>>()), Times.AtLeastOnce());
    call = Expression.Call(param, method, Expression.Constant(true), IsAny<List<T>>());
    Mock.Get(test).Verify(Expression.Lambda<Action<ITest>>(call, param), Times.AtLeastOnce());

    var propertiesParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<T>));
    var checkPropertiesMethod = GetType().GetMethod("CheckProperties", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

    // test.Verify(x => x.METHOD(It.IsAny<bool>(), It.Is<List<T>>(y => y.Count == 0)), Times.Never());
    var checPropertiesCall = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(this), checkPropertiesMethod, propertiesParam, Expression.Constant(0));
    call = Expression.Call(param, method, TestUtils.IsAny<bool>(), TestUtils.Is<EditFieldProperties<T>>(Expression.Lambda<bool>(checPropertiesCall, propertiesParam)));
    Mock.Get(test).Verify(Expression.Lambda<Action<ITest>>(call, param), Times.Never());

    // test.Verify(x => x.METHOD(It.IsAny<bool>(), It.Is<List<int>>(y => y.Count == 2)), Times.Once());
    checPropertiesCall = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(this), checkPropertiesMethod, propertiesParam, Expression.Constant(2));
    call = Expression.Call(param, method, TestUtils.IsAny<bool>(), TestUtils.Is<EditFieldProperties<T>>(Expression.Lambda<bool>(checPropertiesCall, propertiesParam)));
    Mock.Get(test).Verify(Expression.Lambda<Action<ITest>>(call, param), Times.Once());

}
```

In my project I got even further. I extracted all things from 'do stuff' and pass it to `VerifyAnyMethod` as an `Action`. This way i don't even have to setup view each time. It can be done inside `VerifyAnyMethod`.

Comment: Argh, you beat me for a seconds=)

Answer (score 2):

Moq uses expression trees for configuration, so you can generate generic verify rules by building various `Expression<Action<ITest>>` instances. Just an example, how it could be achieved in your particular case:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void Method1(bool readMode, List<int> list);
    void Method2(bool readMode, List<int> list);
    void Method3(bool readMode, List<string> list);
}

[Test]
public void Method1Test()
{
    Mock<ITest> test = new Mock<ITest>();

    TestAnyMethod<ITest, int>(test, "Method1");
    TestAnyMethod<ITest, int>(test, "Method2");
    TestAnyMethod<ITest, string>(test, "Method3");

    test.VerifyAll();
}

private void TestAnyMethod<T, TItem>(Mock<ITest> test, string methodName)
{
    // Arrange
    var type = typeof(T);
    var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);
    test.Setup(Verifiable<TItem>(type, methodInfo)).Verifiable();

    // Act
    // make verifying call via reflection:

    // object.Method#(true, new List<TItem> { .. }))
    methodInfo.Invoke(test.Object, new object[] {true, new List<TItem>{ default(TItem) } });

    // object.Method#(true, new List<TItem> { .. , .. })
    methodInfo.Invoke(test.Object, new object[] {true, new List<TItem> { default(TItem), default(TItem) } });

    // Assert
    test.Verify(VerifyReadMode<TItem>(type, methodInfo, true), Times.AtLeastOnce());
    test.Verify(VerifyReadMode<TItem>(type, methodInfo, false), Times.Never());
    test.Verify(VerifyListCount<TItem>(type, methodInfo, 0), Times.Never());
    test.Verify(VerifyListCount<TItem>(type, methodInfo, 2), Times.Once());
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns x=>x.Method#(It.IsAny`bool`(), It.IsAny`List`int``()
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mockingType">The type that we mock</param>
/// <param name="method">Verifying method</param>
private Expression<Action<ITest>> Verifiable<T>(Type mockingType, MethodInfo method)
{
    var readModeArg = Expression.Call(typeof(It), "IsAny", new []{ typeof(bool) });
    var listArg = Expression.Call(typeof(It), "IsAny", new[] { typeof(List<T>) });

    return Verify(mockingType, method, readModeArg, listArg);
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns x=>x.Method#(<paramref name="readMode"/>, It.IsAny`List`int``()
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mockingType">The type that we mock</param>
/// <param name="method">Verifying method</param>
/// <param name="readMode"></param>
private Expression<Action<ITest>> VerifyReadMode<T>(Type mockingType, MethodInfo method, bool readMode)
{
    var readModeArg = Expression.Constant(readMode);
    var listArg = Expression.Call(typeof(It), "IsAny", new[] { typeof(List<T>) });

    return Verify(mockingType, method, readModeArg, listArg);
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns x=>x.Method#(It.IsAny`bool`(), It.Is`List`int``(y=>y.Count == <paramref name="count"/>)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mockingType">The type that we mock</param>
/// <param name="method">Verifying method</param>
private Expression<Action<ITest>> VerifyListCount<T>(Type mockingType, MethodInfo method, int count)
{
    var readModeArg = Expression.Call(typeof(It), "IsAny", new[] { typeof(bool) });

    var listPrm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<T>), "y");
    var prop = Expression.Property(listPrm, typeof(List<T>), "Count");
    var equal = Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Constant(count));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<T>, bool>>(equal, "y", new [] { listPrm });
    var listArg = Expression.Call(typeof(It), "Is", new[] { typeof(List<T>) }, lambda);

    return Verify(mockingType, method, readModeArg, listArg);
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns lambda expression for verifying <paramref name="method"/> with arguments
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mockingType">The type that we mock</param>
/// <param name="method">Verifying method</param>
/// <param name="readModeArg">Expression for verify readMode argument</param>
/// <param name="listArg">Expression for verify list argument</param>
private Expression<Action<ITest>> Verify(Type mockingType, MethodInfo method, Expression readModeArg, Expression listArg)
{
    var prm = Expression.Parameter(mockingType, "x");
    var methodCall = Expression.Call(prm, method, readModeArg, listArg);
    Expression<Action<ITest>> expr = Expression.Lambda<Action<ITest>>(methodCall, "x", new[] { prm });
    return expr;
}
```

As you can see it is not really elegant solution and usage syntax is not exactly the same as you provided, however example works and it was interesting exercise. Use your own judgement, whether to use it in tests or not.

Hope it helps.

Comment: After 10 hours of work I cam up to similar result :) Thanks for help and for showing another `Expression.Call` that accepts generic method types as parameters.

Comment: Happy to help=)

Answer (score -2):

I think C# has automated testing projects... You can try it, and put the common code in [TestSetup], and the methods in [TestMethod]. From googling you can check the following link [Automated Unit testing - why? what? which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316101/automated-unit-testing-why-what-which)... Hope it helps, and please mark as answer if it solved your question.

Comment: i think this misses the point of the question. OP is asking how to make a test helper generic, not how to create a test project or what to test